# My 16GB SDHC card capacity shrinks from 400 something to 230 something?

Tags: sdhc

I have a 16GB SDHC Ultra II that I use for my Nikon D7000 and I shoot RAW. Before the display in the camera says that it holds around 448 or something pix but now after I transferred some of the pix back to the computer (I used around 200 yesterday) and deleted those in the cards, the camera still shows I have ONLY space for 230 pix in the card.

How can this happen? I have already deleted those pix in the SD card and I have actually re-formatted the card (using the menu in the camera) but still it shows 230 instead of the original 448. Can anyone help?

Comment: Its usually wise to format the card after you've transferred your photos. Many unusual things may happen otherwise. Happened to me before...

Comment: Any result in the meantime?

Comment: After you deleted the files with your computer, did you empty the trash bin? On some computers, deleting files puts them in the "trash" which is still on the same drive. Only after emptying the trash does the file actually get removed.

Answer (score 9):

- What does the computer say about its capacity? Is there still a 16GB partition, or has it perhaps been resized?
- Are you still recording RAW only, or perhaps RAW+FINE? (I guess not though since my 16GB card shows 440 images as well for RAW (14-bit lossless compression), but still 312 for RAW+FINE)
- Did you put another card into the second card slot and chose its role as *Backup card?* This is most probable. The number of images you can shoot when Card 2 is set to Backup is the lower number of images that you can store on either card. If the second card has only 8 GB space left, then it does not matter whether you've got 8 GB or 800 GB on the first card. (Ok, in the latter case science might perhaps be interested in the card.)

Comment: To heck with science, if you got an 800 GB card, ***I'm*** interested in it!

Comment: JoanneC: 512GB is there https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?A=details&O=&Q=&ap=y&c3api=1876%2C%7Bcreative%7D%2C%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=Cj0KCQjwh_bLBRDeARIsAH4ZYEOdSmkZAw2Ml-7Yy8aUFpfJ0gMo2FMcV6N39PF8Y08RqWsNuIeIVrQaAmM8EALw_wcB&is=REG&m=Y&sku=1082352

Answer (score 1):

This camera has two SD card slots; have you got a card in each slot, or just in one? Could it be that you've filled up one card and re-formatted the other?

Guessing that a D7000 14-bit, losslessly compressed raw file is around 19MiB (20 x 10^6 bytes) and that your 16GB card actually has 14.9GiB (16 x 10^9 bytes) of formatted capacity, you should get about 800 pictures per card, not 400. So maybe the card was having issues the first time around as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Sandisk SDHC Extreme pro 32GB card. The display on my Nikon D7200 shows that it can hold 589 RAW pictures. When I use it and shoot some pictures the display shows the remaining photos amount that can be stored on the card.
This amount is incorrect. An average RAW-file uses about 28/29MB. This file size means a 32GB card can hold about 32(GB)x1024(MB)=32768(MB)/29(MB)=1129 RAW size photos. As the User Manual says the capacity is a no exact definition but an estimate.